# WP Query to displaying date and posts for that date?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query

I am trying to create a customized query that would result in the following.

**-- Monday, January 5, 2018 --**

This is a post title from 01-05-2018

This is a post title from 01-05-2018

This is a post title from 01-05-2018

**-- Tuesday, January 6, 2018 --**

This is a post title from 01-06-2018

This is a post title from 01-06-2018

This is a post title from 01-06-2018

**-- Wednesday, January 7, 2018 --**

This is a post title from 01-07-2018

This is a post title from 01-07-2018

This is a post title from 01-07-2018

... and so on.

I have created a query args with the following:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'show',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'  => 'show_date',
        'order' => ASC
    );
```

Which gives me the posts I need but is there a way to inject the date in between each day?

/TIA

Comment: You cant solve this with a query only, you need to loop through the posts, check their date and breakt it up accordingly

Comment: Is the date the date the post was made, or the custom field? If it's the meta value, in what format is the date stored (will help with answering)?

Comment: It is a custom field. "show_date"

Comment: I amended my comment while you were commenting, so in case you missed it: What format is the date stored in (eg. YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD)?

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use the posts date for the post date? Any issues with visibility can be fixed with the `pre_get_posts` filter, and it would be faster than ordering by a meta value

Comment: @JacobPeattie Date is stored as (F j, Y)

Comment: @TomJNowell - I don't see an issue, but the posts will need to be sorted by the show date, rather that the post date.

Comment: You're not going to be able to sort by `F j, Y`. To sort by date you'll need to store it in a format MySQL can understand, like `YYYY-MM-DD` which is `Y-m-d`. Then you can order by setting `meta_value_type` to `DATE` and `orderby` to `meta_value_date`.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie - I got the orderby working with the current meta_value, what I am trying to do now is group the posts by day.

Comment: *Is it* ordering correctly? Or do you just coincidentally have posts whose months are in alphabetical order?

Comment: It is ordering correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this using the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'show',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'show_date',
    'order' => ASC
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $day_check = '';
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

            $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_field('show_date')));

            if ($day != $day_check) {
                if ($day_check != '') {
                  $output .= '</ul>'; // end ul.shows
                }

                $output .= '<h3 class="date">' . date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime(get_field('show_date'))) . '</h3>';
                // start this date's show list
                $output .= '<ul class="shows">';
            }

            // what ever you want to show from the posts
            $output .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

        $day_check = $day;

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: upvoted for answering own question :)